# Possible bug in user-reputation league display (appearance of double row-entry)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I was in my profile and noticed "*top 3% this month*". The ego-stroke was interesting, so I clicked it.

Upon arriving at the league list, no problems; upon clicking the week- or quarter- tabs, the #1 spot (my own, surprisingly) occupied two rows (by double entry, not by vertical aspect being stretched). Clicking the month-tab showed the double row entry as now being present there (where it hadn't been doubled upon my arrival at the page).

The problem persisted in these three tabs, though it didn't show in the year- or all-time- tabs (possibly a telling point, since I'm hardly #1 in either of those tabs).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal, though perhaps a little weird. No matter what time span or sort you look at, your row always appears at the top with the gold highlight. (So you don't have to search through a bunch of pages to find yourself.) The normal ranking appears below that. In this case, you also happen to be number one.

This is what Super User's year rankings look like at the moment:

[image: I appear twice]

Since it's me looking at it, I appear first with all my information, but since I also happen to be #3 (so shown on the first page), my row appears again with the same information.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: Perhaps if the "You are here!" (as it were) were clearly separate from the actual ordered list, then the listing wouldn't throw people (or rather: it might not then continually throw them until they discover the underlying mechanic).