# Feature: a clear separation of the league display quick-reference row w.r.t. the ordered list itself

Tags: feature-request

When viewing the league display, one's own entry row is displayed as a quick reference. If one happens to be at or near the top, this results in the appearance of a double entry. This probably doesn't often result in confusion, and possibly not for long when it does occur; all that I can assert with certainty is that the rate is non-zero. Once one is accustomed to it, the problem is gone, but is liable to occur to anyone upon their first exposure to it (and to continue until clarified for the individual).

**My question is: might it be better to separate them in a more clear manner?**
     The purpose of this would be so that the quick-reference data can't be easily confused for an actual line item within the list itself? (Granting that they are, technically, but not in the same sense: the data are the same, but the Q.R. is only a Q.R., whereas a line item within the ordered list is positional and relative to others' data.)
     Perhaps something as simple as a horizontal rule (presumably with a one-sentence blurb indicating that the above were one's specific data, and the below were the list entries)?

For reference: when I had discovered this, I had initially thought it to be [a possible glitch](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/421/possible-bug-in-user-reputation-league-display-appearance-of-double-row-entry). My name had been the top for the list at that time, and there was no indication (beyond highlighting) that it was one entry of quick-reference and another that was the beginning of the list itself.

Note: this might be fundamental to the S.E./S.O. programming architecture, rather than the chess-specific meta. If it needs migrating to the general S.E. meta (or elsewhere), I'll understand. (Likewise, I suppose that it could be deeply embedded, hence not feasible to restructure on a whim.)